# Pattern for persisting data in Realm?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, realm

My issue is how to organize the code. Let say I have a User class

```
public class User extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    @Required
    private String name;

    public User() { // per requirement of no args constructor
        id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    // Assume getter & setter below...
}
```

and a Util class is needed to handles the save in an asynchronous manner since RealmObjects cannot have methods other than getter/setter.

```
public class Util {
    public static void save(User user, Realm realm) {
        RealmAsyncTask transaction = realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                realm.copyToRealm(user);  // <====== Argument needs to be declared final in parent method's argument!
            }
        }, null);
    }
}
```

The intention is to put save() in a Util class to prevent spreading similar save code all over the code-base so that every time I wanted to save I would just call it as such:

```
User u = new User();
u.setName("Uncle Sam");
Util.save(u, Realm.getDefaultInstance());
```

Not sure if this affects performance at all, but I was just going to save all fields overwriting what was there except for the unique id field every single time.

The problem is that I now need to set the "user" argument as final in the Util.save() method, which means I cannot pass in the object I need to save other than once.

Is there a different way of handling this? Maybe a different pattern? Or am I looking at this all wrong and should go back to SQLite?

Answer (score 1):

Why is it a problem to set `public static void save(final User user, Realm realm)` ? It just means you cannot reassign the `user` variable to something else.

That said, the existence of a `save()` method can be a potential code smell as you then spread the update behaviour across the code base. I would suggest looking into something like the Repository pattern (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) instead.

Realm is actually working on an example showing how you can combine the Model-View-Presenter architecture with a Repository to encapsulate updates which is a good pattern for what you are trying to do here. You can see the code for it here: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/1960

Comment: I think the first mistake was that in `public static void save(final User user, Realm realm)`, I made it final which means it only applies to one user which is obviously not true. I have not heard of the Repository pattern, and to my understanding it is essentially an abstraction between the ORM and whatever needs the data like the view in one place? However, the way it is done with an anonymous class will always require `final` keyword due to Java's way of handling closure. How can I get around to being able to pass in a User to be saved?